# GIT: How to add a forgotten commit (in master) to a new branch

Tags: git

An hour ago, I created a new branch (spawned from the master branch) and pushed it to the remote. However, a co-worker forgot to commit/push his local changes, so he just committed it now into the master branch. How do I ensure that this commit is also reflected in the new branch I created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your local repository and the remote look like this.

```
origin
A - B - C - G - H [master]
         \
          E - F [feature]

local
          [master]
A - B - C [origin/master]
         \
          E - F [origin/feature]
                [feature]
```

G and H are the commits to master your co-worker pushed, but you haven't fetched yet.

First, update your master with a `git pull`. This will fetch any changes and merge the into your local master branch.

```
$ git checkout master
$ git pull

origin
A - B - C - G - H [master]
         \
          E - F [feature]

local
                  [master]
A - B - C - G - H [origin/master]
         \
          E - F [origin/feature]
                [feature]
```

Then update your branch with the latest commits from master by merging.

```
$ git checkout branch
$ git merge master

origin
A - B - C - G - H [master]
         \
          E - F [feature]

local
                  [master]
A - B - C - G - H [origin/master]
         \       \
          E - F - M [feature] (at merge commit M)
              [origin/feature] (still at commit F)
```

Then `git push` your changes.

```
$ git push

origin
                  
A - B - C - G - H [master]
         \       \
          E - F - M [feature]

local
                  [master]
A - B - C - G - H [origin/master]
         \       \
          E - F - M [feature]
                    [origin/feature] (now at M)
```

---

Alternatively, you can `rebase` your work. This is a little more complex, but the results are better.

Instead of merging your commits will be replayed on top of the latest master.

```
$ git checkout branch
$ git rebase master

origin
A - B - C - G - H [master]
         \
          E - F [feature]

local
                  [master]
A - B - C - G - H [origin/master]
         \       \
          \        E1 - F1 [feature]
           \
            E - F [origin/feature]
```

Because `feature` and `origin/feature` have "diverged" a `git push` will result in an error. Instead, use [`git push --force-with-lease`](https://blog.developer.atlassian.com/force-with-lease/) to safely push the divergent changes.

```
origin
A - B - C - G - H [master]
                 \
                   E1 - F1 [feature]

local
                  [master]
A - B - C - G - H [origin/master]
                 \
                  E1 - F1 [feature]
                          [origin/feature]
```

Now there is no "update" merge. Many update merges can clog up the history making it difficult to tell what was done in the branch.

If others on the project try to `git pull` your branch they will get an error because the new commits are not simple children of the branch. They will have to pull your branch with `git pull --rebase`. I recommend this. You can make it the default with `git config --global pull.rebase merge`.

Comment: I performed the first steps you described and it seems to have done the trick. I don't quite understand the alternate solution (rebase) but I hope I didn't create any problems. You say "the results are better" with the rebase solution, so this worries me.

Comment: @Ray Don't worry, rebase or merge you'll come out with the same code in the branch. The difference is the rebase process produces a simpler history and the conflict management can be easier when updating old branches. Merging is the norm. You can revisit the rebase process once you've gained more Git experience.

Answer (score 1):

Fetching the remote branch and rebasing your branch on it is the easiest way to, ie.

```
git fetch origin
git checkout <branch>
git rebase origin/master
```

For more details see: https://git-scm.com/book/de/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing